# C++ Calling return member function outputs "?before initialization"

Tags: c++, initialization, output

When I run this code, I get this output.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //Create
    Date date = Date(1 , 1, 2000);
    std::string str = date.GetDate();
    std::cout << "Initial parameters: " << str << "\n";

    //Use setters to change
    date.SetDay(30);
    date.SetMonth(5);
    date.SetYear(1999);
    std::cout << "Used setters: " << date.GetDate() << "\n";

    //Input invalid parameters
    date.SetDay(0);
    date.SetMonth(13);
    std::cout << "Set day to 0, month to 13: " << date.GetDate() << "\n";
}
```

Date.h

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <string>

class Date {
public:
    Date(unsigned int, unsigned int, int);
    void SetMonth(unsigned int);
    void SetDay(unsigned int);
    void SetYear(int);
    std::string GetDate() const;
    unsigned int GetMonth() const;
    unsigned int GetDay() const;
    int GetYear() const;

private:
    unsigned int month{ 1 };
    unsigned int day{ 1 };
    int year{ 0 };
};

#endif
```

Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <string>

Date::Date(unsigned int month, unsigned int day, int year) {
    SetMonth(month);
    SetDay(day);
    SetYear(year);
}

void Date::SetMonth(unsigned int month) {
    if (month > 12 || month < 1) this->month = 1;
    else this->month = month;
}

void Date::SetDay(unsigned int day) {
    if (day < 1) this->day = 1;
    else this->day = day; //TODO upper day limit (not for this exercise though hahahahaaaa)
}

void Date::SetYear(int year) {
    this->year = year;
}

std::string Date::GetDate() const {
    std::string output;
    output = GetMonth();
    output += "/" + GetDay();
    output += "/" + GetYear();
    return output;
}

unsigned int Date::GetMonth() const { return month; }

unsigned int Date::GetDay() const { return day; }

int Date::GetYear() const { return year; }
```

[image]

**TLDR main.cpp lines 12, 18, and 23 call the member function GetDate() - prototyped Date.h line 12 and defined Date.cpp line 24 - on an object of my custom Date class. Instead of outputting what it's supposed to, it outputs "?before initialization".**

In place of `date.GetDate()` it prints "?before initialization". *What* is before initialization? The function? The member fields are all initialized. In fact, if I call and output *just* one of the member fields, such as `std::cout << date.GetDay()`, it prints just fine. And why does it print a smiley face or a club?

Comment: `output += "/" + GetDay();` is a suspect line. The [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is such that this expands to `output += ("/" + GetDay());`. Which means I'm surprised this compiles, I wouldn't expect `+` to even work for `const char[2]` and `unsigned int`. ETA: Pointer arithmetic! Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator in `"/" + GetDay()` and `"/" + GetYear()` are not concatenating strings but moving the pointer pointing at the first element of the array `"/"` (`{'/', '\0'}`) `GetDay()` and `GetYear()` elements ahead.

`GetYear()` returns a large value, so the pointer goes to some "random" position and `before initialization` seems happened to be there. It should be used in somewhere else in the library used.

Instead of this, you can use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to concatenate strings and integers like this:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string Date::GetDate() const {
    std::stringstream output;
    output << GetMonth();
    output << "/" << GetDay();
    output << "/" << GetYear();
    return output.str();
}
```

Comment: Or, more concisely, the [string literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Comment: I see... it seems I've encountered something my class hasn't taught me about yet. Thanks!

Comment: See [std::basic_string::operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) The thing to note in the cases (1) ... (5) is that all arguments on the right-hand-side are type `basic_string` or `CharT` (string or character), not integer values. Bookmark [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) -- best reference on the internet...